# How to re-route/recreate POST request with file data in Flask

Tags: python, flask, post

I'm trying to forward a file upload POST request my Python Flask webservice receives to another API. I already receive the request in a format that the API would accept, however, I was not able to find any way to take the request I received and directly forward it to the API. I had imagined that maybe something like this could exist:

```
requests.post("url_of_api", request)
```

Where `request` is Flask's representation of the received request. Is such a thing possible?

Alternatively, I'm trying to recreate a request with the same data. The problem is that the request contains a file upload (wav specifically). I've tried to create a request with the file data as follows:

```
requests.post("url_of_api",files={"audio_data":("test.wav",request.files["audio_data"].stream.read())})
```

I can see in Wireshark that the requests are almost identical in respect to their file representation, however, there are slight differences at the start and end of the bytestream and file in the second request has 46 fewer bytes of data. In addition, it loses its MIME-type. Is there any way to exactly replicate the byte representation of the uploaded file in a new request?